# Laravel migration - add new column to 50 millions data

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

Is there any alternative to add new column to table that has 50 millions data?

I tried it with migration, and my database is down after trying to add 45 mins.

Is there any other solution to handle this operation?

Comment: What it means: 50millions data to the column. Do you mean 50 million characters in that exact column (in 1 record) ??

Comment: @boolfalse I would guess 50 million rows, but its a guess

Comment: yeah thats right, I got 50 million rows yet. and I can't add any new column because database downs when try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good choice to alter a table which is populated with a large data set. As alternative you can always create a new table with the required column and make a relationship on that column to the table. It will be a effective way to do this.